# Map Annotations Not Showing on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

So I have a really bizarre issue and cannot figure out for the life of me why this is an issue.

Basically I create an array of annotations and add them to the map...simple!
When I run my code on an iPhone 6 or above (both on a real device and the simulator) the annotations appear as I expect.

If I run my code on an iPhone 5 (real device or simulator) the annotations don't appear. It's exactly the same code!

I then decided to create a simple print statement to the log "Adding Friend Annotation" to ensure that `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` was being called.

To my surprise, anything above an iPhone 5 is getting called no problem, however on an iPhone 5 it never gets called apart from when it adds the MKUser annotation.

I am completely stuck on this and would appreciate any advice...thanks.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        returnUserBadgeColour()
        print("ADDING USER ANNOTATION")
        userRiderView = MKAnnotationView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40, height: 40))
        userRiderView.image = UIImage(named:"\(userHaloColour)")
        userRiderView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        userRiderView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        userRiderView.clipsToBounds = false

        circle.image = UIImage(named:"\(userBadgeColour)")
        userRiderView.addSubview(circle)

        let userlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 26, height: 22))
        userlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Oswald-Regular", size: 17.0)
        userlabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        userlabel.textAlignment = .center
        userlabel.text = initials
        userRiderView.addSubview(userlabel)
        userlabel.center = CGPoint(x: (userRiderView.frame.width)/2, y: (userRiderView.frame.height)/2)

        return userRiderView
    }

    else if (annotation is FriendsAnnotation) {
        print("ADDING FRIEND ANNOTATION")

        friendRiderView = MKAnnotationView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40, height: 40))
        friendRiderView.image = UIImage(named:"\(userHaloColour)")
        friendRiderView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        friendRiderView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        let circle = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 5.0, width: 70, height: 70))
        let colour = (annotation as! FriendsAnnotation).friendColor
        circle.image = UIImage(named:"\(colour)")
        friendRiderView.addSubview(circle)

        let friendLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 26, height: 22))
        friendLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Oswald-Regular", size: 17)
        friendLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        friendLabel.textAlignment = .center
        friendLabel.text = (annotation as! FriendsAnnotation).friendsInitialsA
        friendRiderView.addSubview(friendLabel)
        friendLabel.center = CGPoint(x: (friendRiderView.frame.width)/2, y: (friendRiderView.frame.height)/2)

        return friendRiderView
    }

    else {
        print("ADDING ANY ANNOTATION")
        let any: MKAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView ()
        return any
    }
```

Comment: Which iOS version are you running on iPhone 5 ?

Comment: Hey GIJOW, so I managed to track down the issue today. Basically it was a JSON issue. So I had to backstep through my code quite a long way to establish the issue. Oddly it seems that the iPhone 5 handles JSON slightly differently, it doesn’t seem to like blank values whereas any device above an iPhone 5 doesn’t care about zero values! If a blank value is found on the iPhone 5 it disregards the entire object! Because of this it wasn’t appending anything to my annotations array which in turn means it had no annotations to add to the map!

Comment: glad you found the issue !